# how can I show that $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$ is continuous on $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f\in L^1(0,1)$. For $x\in [0,1]$, we define $$F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt.$$ How can I show that $F$ is continuous ?

What I tried is $$\lim_{h\to 0}F(x+h)-F(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\int_x^{x+h}f(t)dt=\int_x^x f(t)dt=0,$$
it's continuous, but my teacher said that I can't do that since my last equality doesn't work if $F$ is not continuous but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3):

Your teacher is right, since when you write $$\lim_{h\to 0}\int_x^{x+h}f(t)\mathrm d t=\int_x^x f(t)\mathrm d t,$$
you mean $$\lim_{h\to 0}F(x+h)\underset{(*)}{=}F(\lim_{h\to 0} x+h)=F(x).$$
Since $(*)$ provided $F$ is continuous, you can't do as you did. On the other side,
$$\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)\mathrm d t=\int f(t)\chi_{[x,x+h]}(t)\mathrm d t.$$
Now,
$$|f(t)\chi_{[x,x+h]}(t)|\leq |f(t)|\in L^1(0,1).$$
Therefore, you can use dominated convergence theorem, and conclude.